# Are links always bookmarkable?

Tags: wicket

I created an ordinary link, nothing fancy:

```
    Link<Integer>link=new Link<Integer>("link") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            setResponsePage(MyTarget.class);

        }
    };
```

In HTML I see:

```
<a wicket:id="link" href="./?0-3.ILinkListener-link">link</a>
```

When I click the link, I see in the URL field:

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/my.test.own.wicket_quickstart.MyTarget
```

So are my links always bookmarkable?

Comment: It might be for stateless pages. That would make sense. Try linking to a stateful page and see if you get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket links are mostly internal links and you cannot be sure about the generated URL. If you want to get an bookmarkable link, use Bookmarkable link instead. http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html

```
Link<Integer>link = new Bookmarkable<Integer>("link", MyTarget.class);
```

If you want to have a nice URL, use page mounting / request mappin, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Request+mapping

Answer (score 0):

No.

Links will redirect you somewhere. If you use a Bookmarkable Page and `setResponsePage` you will get a nice redirected url.

You can also use a link to change some model value

```
 Link<Integer>link=new Link<Integer>("link") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            myModel.setObject("Great success!");

        }
    };
```

In this case you will be taken back to your page.